# Changing aspx website urls

Tags: asp.net, http, url, url-rewriting, get

I have a web site. URLs **com/default.aspx** form should appear. But when I click on the URL (**com/(S (the hito5tqogutqn21tcn2mozjrr))/default.aspx**) as it seems. How do I fix it. URLs with a random number itself is changing.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

This is happening probably because (unless, you have specified explicitly to use the uri for session id management, which I think, is not the case) the browser does not allow cookies (either for your web site or for all) and Asp.Net detects this and appends the session id to the uri because otherwise your site would not be able to support sessions.

In fact, this is the most secure approach, allowing session state to be available even if the user had disabled cookies.

You can change this behaviour by specifying the following in your web.config file:

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
  </system.web>
```

After that, you will not see the session Id in the Uri, but users whose browsers do not accept cookies from your web site will not be able to have a session state.

At this point, defining a privacy policy for your web site might help your cookies to be accepted by the browsers:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx